# Deploying Swift to Server without Vapor

Tags: swift, heroku, server, vapor, command-line-tool

This may be a silly question, but I've been looking for information about deploying a Swift backend to hosting services like Heroku without using the Vapor framework.  Are frameworks like Vapor necessary for Swift server projects? as I use (and prefer) a lower-level library for WebSockets that is (imo) easier than implementing in Vapor.

I guess the question is, how to deploy a command-line-tool to the server without Vapor.

Thanks.

Comment: In general, [Swift can be deployed to various platforms](https://swift.org/platform-support/). For Heroku, consider searching [Swift on Heroku](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Swift+on+Heroku&t=ffab&atb=v177-1&ia=web). Command line interface & REPL are [inherently part of the Swift install per the Getting Started info](https://swift.org/getting-started/). This question is broad and could be improved by asking a more specific use case.